# InstallShield LE : RegOpenKeyEx fails in custom action

Tags: registry, installshield, custom-action

I need to execute some additional configuration after installation so I have created a smoll PostInstall.exe console application which should do the work. I need to get winamp install path from the registry.

This PostInstall.exe works fine if I run it alone. But if I use it in custom action "After Register Product", I get an error "The system cannot find the file specified" returned from the function

```
DWORD kres  =  RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Winamp",0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey);
```

I am 100% sure that the key exists - I verify it before I launch installation. Also when I run PostInstall.exe manually after installation, it succeeds.

I have tried to set "Deferred Execution" and "Deferred execution in system context" but that 
does not help.

Why does RegOpenKeyEx fail in my custom action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the installation is not being elevated under another user account. This way your custom action process will not be executed for a different user which has a different HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive.

Also, try getting the current user inside your custom code and determine if it's the one you expect.